# Yii2: How to detect ActiveForm validation on submit

Tags: ajax, validation, yii2, active-form

We have a form that includes fields Hours and Days. Either hours or days must be specified, but not both. We're using a modal form, Ajax and custom validation rules and all is working fine to ensure one or other is specified and valid when completing the form. However, the time to check at least one or other is specified is when the form is submitted.

The problem is how to differentiate between "normal" validation performed on a field-by-field basis and validation performed on submit. Is there a way to detect when the form is submitted (validateOnSubmit) as opposed to when the form data is posted for validation while it's being entered (validateOnChange)?

This can be checked on final model validation, but at that point it's a standard request so the form is rendered normally instead of updating the modal form.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: conditional required rules:

```
[['days'], 'required', 'message' => 'Days or Hours?', 
           'when' => function($model) { return is_null($model->hours );},
           'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value){ return $('#downtime-hours').val() == '';}",
        ],
[['hours'], 'required', 'message' => 'Hours or Days?', 
            'when' => function($model) { return is_null($model->days); },
            'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value){ return $('#downtime-days').val() == '';}",
        ],
```